# How to unload a mvvmcross v3 plugin (e.g MvxMessenger )?

Tags: mvvmcross

the Messenger Plugin run Mvx.RegisterSingleton(new MvxMessengerHub()); in the first load, but I can't dispose it.

Comment: Can you explain more? e.g. why do you need to dispose it?

Comment: I want to load and unload plugin within the app